# pollingDuplexHttpBinding problem

Tags: wcf

I am using pollingDuplexHttpBinding and it is working fine as long as i copy paste the web.config from msdn article :- [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28VS.95%29.aspx)

However when i try to manually configure my service using WCF configuration editor, it doesn't work. The option `pollingDuplexHttpBinding` doesn't show up under endpoints in Binding drop down box. How do i solve this problem? I already have a reference to the required assembly of pollingduplexhttpbinding.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

Just because it doesn't show up in config intellisense, doesn't mean that the binding won't work when you run your application. Make sure that you have the latest version of Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio installed; Even then, it may still not show up (config intellisense unfortunately always seems to be an afterthought at Microsoft, especially for server-side config for Silverlight scenarios).